# How to write any variable created in a test to the jasmine-reporters output file using Protractor?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

In parts of my test, I have some variables I dynamically create that simply capture some strings.  I have jasmine-reporters set up and working, and writing to an output.xml file.  How do I get any variables I create in my tests to write to that output file?

For example, if I do a search in my test, the results display number of lines in a string as part of what's returned.  I do a getText() on that and store in a variable.  I have figured out how to write to console, but it would be great to get it to write to the output file instead.

Comment: jasmine-reporters does not have any support for adding extra data from tests into JUnit or NUnit XML output. The reporters interface exposed by Jasmine is pretty generic, it gets info about the spec that ran (name, failures, skipped) but not the context of the spec, variables, etc. So you would need to hack something in to Jasmine, then into jasmine-reporters to read that. It doesn't sound like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes like @bloveridge mentioned, jasmine does not allow you to add data from the tests into the report, and you should not try to do it as it's not the concern of the test reporter. If you want to use protractor to collect some kind of information while testing, you should write into your own (i.e. separate) file (http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) in your test.